# $X_{1},X_{2} \sim N(0,1)$ and are independent. Show $\frac{X_{1}}{X_{2}}$ and $\sqrt{X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}}$ are independent

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I know $U=\frac{X_{1}}{X_{2}}$ is a Cauchy distribution and $V=\sqrt{X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}}$ is a Rayleigh distribution since $X_{1},X_{2} \; iid\sim N(0,1)$.

I thought that I can find r.v. $R$ and $\theta$ so that $X_{1}=Rsin\theta$ and $X_{2}=Rcos\theta$. So, $P(U|V)=P(U=tan\theta|V=R)=P(U=tan\theta)=P(U) \Rightarrow U,V\;independent$.

But... do there really exist such r.v. $R$ and $\theta$ $s.t. X_{1}=Rsin\theta,X_{2}=Rcos\theta\;iid \sim N(0,1)$?

And is my idea correct to solve the problem?

Comment: You need to show that for $u,v\in\mathbb R$, $$\mathbb P(U\leqslant u, V\leqslant v) = \mathbb P(U\leqslant u)\mathbb P(V\leqslant v).$$ I'm not sure of an easy way to do this, however.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2959094/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2266214/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128364/321264.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $X_1,X_2$ are independent, the joint PDF is

$$\tag{1}f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x_1^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x_2^2/2} = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(x_1^2 + x_2^2)/2}$$

For $(X_1,X_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have $(U,V) \in (-\infty, \infty)\times [0,\infty)$ under the mapping

$$U = \frac{X_1}{X_2}, \quad V = \sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2}$$

However, it is not one-to-one since points $(X_1,X_2)$ and $(-X_1,-X_2)$ have the same image. There is also a problem of how $U$ is defined when $X_2 = 0$, but this can be ignored by setting $U$ to be $0$ on this set of probability mass $0$.

The joint PDF of $U,V$ can be obtained as

$$\tag{2}f_{U,V}(u,v) = 2f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1(u,v),x_2(u,v)) |J(u,v)|,$$

where the factor of $2$  accounts for the two-to-one nature of the mapping and the Jacobian $J$ is obtained from the inverse mapping $x_1 = \frac{uv}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}, x_2 =\frac{v}{\sqrt{1 + u^2}} $ as

$$\tag{3}|J(u,v)| = \left|\frac{\partial(x_1,x_2)}{\partial(u,v)} \right|= \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial u }\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial v }-\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial v }\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial u } = \frac{v}{1 + u^2}$$

Substituting into (2) using (1) and (3) we obtain

$$f_{U,V}(u,v) = \frac1{\pi(1+u^2)}ve^{-v^2/2}$$

Since the joint PDF factors into a product of a function of $u$ and a function of $v$, the random variables $U$ and $V$ are independent.

Comment: You mention a two-to-one mapping, I dont really see that could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Oh never-mind I see you explain it is because both U and V have a two to one mapping. What would happen to this factor is U had a two-to-one mapping and V has a one-to-one mapping?

Comment: Could you please potentially give me some sort of reference I can look up that would tell me more about this factor?

Answer (score 1):

**Just An idea**:

*Fact 1*: A random vector $x\sim N(0, I_n)$ has the property that
$\|x\|$ and $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ are independent where $\|\cdot \|$
is the Euclidean norm.

*Fact 2*: Functions of independent random variables are also independent.

From Facts 1 and 2, the desired result follows. Indeed, for $n=2$,
$\frac{x}{\|x\|} = [\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}, \ \frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}]$
and $\|x\| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ are independent, 
so are $\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ and $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$.