# Independence of $U=\sqrt{X^2 +Y^2}$ and $V=\frac{X}{Y}$ where $X$ & $Y$ are independent

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, normal-distribution, independence

This is my first class back to school in a few years so sorry if this is simple.

Given $U=\sqrt{X^2 +Y^2}$ and $V=\frac{X}{Y}$ where $X$ & $Y$ are independent identical normally distributed random variables, to prove their independence can I simply show that (where $EX = E[X]$ or the expectation of random variable $X$):
$$
EU = \sqrt{(EX)^2 + (EY)^2}\\
EV = \frac{EX}{EY}\\
$$
\begin{align}
E[V\cdot U] &=E\left[\frac{X}{Y}\sqrt{X^2 +Y^2}\right]\\
 &= \frac{EX}{EY}\sqrt{(EX)^2 + (EY)^2} = EV\cdot EU
\end{align}

Is this all I need to prove they are independent?

Comment: Do you mean $V=\frac{X}{Y}$?

Comment: Yes, fixing that now

Comment: It is not generally the case that $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Take for example a r.v. $X$ with distribution $p_X(-1) = p_X(1) = 1/2$ and $Y = 2X$.

Comment: @gabrimev, so instead of using expectation values, I should maybe try to use distribution functions to show that $F_{UV}=F_{U}F_{V}$?

Comment: @Tsangares Yes, this would do it! In fact just by showing that the joint distribution $F_{UV}$ can be factored as a product where one term depends only on $U$ and the other only on $V$ is enough to show that $U$ and $V$ are independent, even without finding out $F_U$ and $F_V$ explicitly.

Comment: It is not true that $\operatorname E\sqrt{X^2+Y^2} = \sqrt{(\operatorname EX)^2 + (\operatorname E Y)^2}. \qquad$

Comment: @gabrimev, Oh thats sounds really good. Can I simply say that $F_U = \sqrt{F_X^2 + F_Y^2}$?

Comment: Not really unfortunately, the argument would be more along the lines of what Michael answered here. If you are interested on a more general method to determine the joint distribution of functions of random variables (as $U$ and $V$ here), Lecture 2 in [this link](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec1-5.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: @gabrimev Thank you so much!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3431923/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128364/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you for the reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposition is true if the expected values of $X$ and $Y$ are $0.$ It is not true more generally.

No generality is lost be assuming the standard deviation of each of $X,Y$ is $1,$ and I will do that.

The joint density is
$$
\text{constant}\times e^{-x^2/2} \cdot e^{-y^2/2} = \text{constant}\times e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}.
$$
This depends on $(x,y)$ only through the sum of their squares. If you convert to polar coordinates you get
$$
e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \, d(x,y) = e^{-r^2/2} r\, dr\,d\theta
$$
where the factor of $r$ is a Jacobian determinant. (Based on geometry one can argue that it's really $(dr)(r\,d\theta).$)

You get a function of $r$ multiplied by a function of $\theta.$ That shows that the random variables corresponding to $r$ and $\theta$ are independent.

And $x/y= \cot\theta,$ i.e. it depends on $(r,\theta)$ only through $\theta.$

Answer (score 1):

This case involves calculation of expectation of function of independent variables. Thus, calculation is not as simple as directly using the expectation function and its properties here. A better and more robust method is to use function transformation using jacobian matrix.

One considers the transformation $(x,y)\mapsto(u,v)$. The Jacobian is $J(x,y)=-\frac{1}{y^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $, hence
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac1{|J(x,y)|}f_u(u)f_v(v)$$.

Now you can proceed in $u$ and $v$ as you would normally do for independent variables $x$ and $y$.

Comment: How exactly do I use the Jacobian to prove its independence?

Comment: This will help in forgetting x and y and simply concentrating only on u and v to prove independence. You can simply treat u and v as the only variables removing every trace of x and y.